# Command to show turtlebot3 packages have been installed

Tags: package-management

I have installed the turtlebot using the command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-* -y
```

After this I have updated cache using:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Now I need to check turtlebot3 packages show up. For this I was asked to:

> Execute the command: `roscd turtlebot3-`
>
> Press <kbd>tab</kbd> 2 or 3 times and if packages do not show up, restart the
>   computer.

I have tried both pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> and  restarting Ubuntu. But no luck. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dpkg -l | grep ros-kinetic
```

then you may want to show details for specific package like this

```
dpkg -L <packagename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You  all for the responses and fantastic support. The actual problem was that the bashsrc file had both kinetic and groovy distros executing for ros. so when I commented all the groovy commands,as we are using kinetic, all the errors got resolved automatically.

Thanks
Pallavi.